# getDerivedStateFromProps Does not re-render after Redux Reducer state is updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm using the new `getDerivedStateFromProps` since `componentWillReceiveProps` was deprecated. However it does not seem to work as expected, as nothing happens after I update the Redux state.

**Expected**

- Action / Reducer is updated
- Component Main's `props.modal` is updated and the component re-renders

**Results**

- Action / Reducer is updated
- Nothing happens in the Main Component

---

```
"react": "^16.3.2",
"react-dom": "^16.3.2",
```

Note here in this screenshot, I'm able to update the Redux state, `modal` has been updated, yet my component does not update and re-render.

[image]

I expect this code to be called a 2nd time:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, nextState) {
  const { modal } = nextProps;
  console.log('getDerivedStateFromProps', nextProps);
  console.log(' nextState', nextState);
  return { modal };
}
```

Or at least the console.log's in my render method to be called a twice time, this never happens. Any ideas why?

#### Component code:

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
 import { connect } from "react-redux";

 // MUI
 import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

 // Components
 import TopNav from "components/Common/topNav";
 // import ProductModal from 'components/Common/productModal';

 // Utils
 import { findNotification, showNotification } from "utils/notifications";

 const styles = {
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    height: "100%"
  }
  };

  class Main extends Component {
   static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, nextState) {
    const { modal } = nextProps;
    console.log("getDerivedStateFromProps", nextProps);
    console.log(" nextState", nextState);
    return { modal };
}

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        modal: {}
    };
}

componentDidUpdate(props) {
    console.log("componentDidUpdate", props);
}

render() {
    const {
        classes,
        children,
        notifications,
        currentNotification
    } = this.props;

    console.log("this.props", this.props);
    console.log("this.state", this.state);

    const notificationObj = findNotification(
        currentNotification,
        notifications
    );

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            {/* <ProductModal /> */}
            <TopNav />
            {showNotification(notificationObj)}
            {children}
        </div>
    );
}
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ modal }) => ({
modal
});

export const MainJest = Main;

export default connect(
mapStateToProps,
null
)(withStyles(styles)(Main));
```

#### Reducer:

```
import {
  MODAL_CLOSE_MODAL,
  MODAL_SET_MODAL
} from 'actions/types';

export const initialState = {
  modal: {
    name: '',
    props: {}
  }
};

const modalsReducer = (state = initialState, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case MODAL_SET_MODAL:
      return {
        ...state,
        modal: {
          name: payload.modalName,
          props: payload.modalProps
        }
      };
    case MODAL_CLOSE_MODAL:
      return {
        ...state,
        modal: {
          name: '',
          props: {}
        }
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default modalsReducer;
```

Comment: could you please share the reducer? This is what I think that could be happening: if the reducer is mutating the previous object, then `modal` will always be the same instance and then SCU will prevent the re-render of the base component

Comment: @Josep reducer added!

Comment: Well, it wasn't that... :-) Next question: what version of React are you using?

Comment: Out of curiosity, does `export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Main);` render properly?

Comment: @Josep I'm using this version of React `^16.3.2`

Comment: @Dom Yes after I remove the `classes` that are used, it will render. However the bug remains, after I update the Redux state with a Modal name, the Main component does not re-render :'(

Comment: what if you swap `connect` and `withStyles`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my problem was in the `mapStateToProps`

Needed to pull the state from `modalsReducer`

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log('mapStateToProps state:', state);
  return state.modalsReducer;
};
```

Also needed to flatten my state inside the `modalsReducer`

```
import {
  MODAL_CLOSE_MODAL,
  MODAL_SET_MODAL
} from 'actions/types';

export const initialState = {
  modalName: '',
  modalProps: {}
};

const modalsReducer = (state = initialState, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case MODAL_SET_MODAL:
      return {
        ...state,
        modalName: payload.modalName,
        modalProps: payload.modalProps
      };
    case MODAL_CLOSE_MODAL:
      return {
        ...state,
        modalName: '',
        modalProps: {}
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default modalsReducer;
```

So the Redux was not connected properly...